# Translation for “FAQ" in a web interface context

Tags: choix-de-mot, informatique

What's the best translation for "FAQ" (frequently asked questions) in a website context?

*Questions Fréquemment Posées* or *Foire Aux Questions*?

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to base your translation on prevalent usage instead of whether it originated as a calque of English, I would say that those two are good choices, or simply « FAQ ». Here's a University of Montreal [page](https://admission.umontreal.ca/admission/foire-aux-questions/questions-et-reponses/) called « Foire aux questions », for example, and here's [one from the Sorbonne](http://www.paris-sorbonne.fr/faq-speciale-rentree).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion, those two (widely used) translations are somehow english-driven:

- "Foire Aux Questions" matches the acronym FAQ.
- "Questions fréquemment posées" is a litteral translation of the english.

I think "Questions fréquentes", "Questions courantes" or "Questions - Réponses"
is more idiomatic, and for once there are fewer words in french.

Comment: Picked this as best answer because it's less words and not literally translated from English.

Comment: Voir aussi au [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2076493), qui regroupe certains des choix que vous présentez. Merci !

Answer (score 7):

**What's the best translation for “FAQ" in a web interface context?**
I think it's a matter of opinion, but here is mine.

---

*Foire aux questions* is commonly used because it matches the English acronym. But – in my opinion – is does not mean anything in French and it sounds a bit familiar.

From [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/foire/34375), *foire* in French means:

> - Grand marché se tenant à des époques fixes dans un même lieu
> - Fête foraine ayant une périodicité régulière
> - Endroit où tout est en désordre, où l'on fait du bruit (*familier*)

I think we understand the term *Foire aux questions* because we are used to the web, but for a person who has never seen this term (an elderly person, for example), I do not think it is very understandable.

So, for a professional website, I would suggest to use *Questions fréquemment posées* instead. I think it is really clearer, so much for the acronym.

Answer (score 3):

Both of your suggestions are common although you shouldn't capitalize any word but the first (e.g. *Questions fréquemment posées*.)

*Foire aux questions* is often used because it matches the English acronym but if you want something less informal, you might write:

> *Questions - réponses*